# Why <form action="index.html"> changes on <form action="about:blank"> in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, textarea

Create file index.html with this code:

```
<html> 
<body>
<form action="index.html" method="post">
<textarea name="content">
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Open this file in Google Chrome.
Enter in textarea this text

> action="index.html"

and press submit button.
Open Developer Tools (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) and see this

```
<html> 
<body>
<form action="about:blank" method="post">
<textarea name="content">
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Why **action="index.html"** replaced by **action="about:blank"**?

Problem exists only in Google Chrome, current version 28.0.1500.72 m.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the XSS filter from chrome. It changes `action` on forms it think are injections, for `about:blank` (among other things)

Try sending `X-XSS-Protection: 0` header to disable it.

So, its not a bug, its a feature.

Read more about it here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83503